# How to draw 2 PNG Images to the screen at the same time

Tags: android, image, png, draw, imageview

I'd like to know how to draw two PNG pictures onto the screen.

My XML layout:  (named paperxml.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/paperid"
        android:src="@drawable/paperrepresentation"
    />

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rockid"
        android:src="@drawable/rockrepresentation"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/paperid"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What would be the java code to instantiate the XML layout and display both ImageViews on the screen at the same time?
Simply calling `setContentView(R.drawable.paperxml);` crashes my application on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/paperid"
        android:src="@drawable/paperrepresentation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/rockid"
        android:src="@drawable/rockrepresentation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Explanation:

- `RelativeLayout` doesn't use  `android:orientation="vertical"`.
- Every view should have `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`.
- Add the `xmlns:android` thing just in the first element.

Comment: I put the XML in but it only displays one ImageView
Here's a screenshot of the emulator I took.
http://i852.photobucket.com/albums/ab87/thomasjakway1/Capture.png

Its worth mentioning that the file shown is paperrepresentation

Comment: That's because of the size. Try playing with the `layout_width` and `layout_height` use something like "40dp".
Also remember that the LinearLayout is set to Vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setContentView(R.drawable.paperxml);` is not crashing your code - it's your XML file.   Macarse has the correct answer to your problem, and keep your code the same!

You may also want to look at the [View Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) for some examples of setting up your XML and using different View objects.

Answer (score 0):

> I put the XML in but it only displays one ImageView Here's a screenshot of the emulator I took. i852.photobucket.com/albums/ab87/thomasjakway1/Capture.png Its worth mentioning that the file shown is paperrepresentation

If you look hard enough you will see that at the bottom there is a second very tiny image. You just need to increase the scale.